# How can I change color text of status bar in Android?

Tags: android

I want to change text color of action bar in Android Studio:
[image: Colored bar]

```xml
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the status bar as light theme color, you can just add following line in your `styles.xml`:

```xml
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```